# System.OverflowException in decimal

Tags: c#

Here I am working on project in C#. But when I run function with this code program fall with this [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaY0g.png).

```
jx += Convert.ToDecimal(-6164.64/ ((Math.Log10(Convert.ToDouble(0.434294D *Math.Log10(Convert.ToDouble( 0.813008D*(decimal.ToDouble(vyteznost_CO2_s_vysokym_tlakem * 1000000 * mars_g_acceleration) / martian_surface))))))));
```

Comment: What is the value of `-6164.64/ ((Math.Log10(Convert.ToDouble(0.434294D *Math.Log10(Convert.ToDouble( 0.813008D*(decimal.ToDouble(vyteznost_CO2_s_vysokym_tlakem * 1000000 * mars_g_acceleration) / martian_surface)))))))` returns? Looks like it's outside of `decimal` boundaries. Put it on a variable and see it's value.

Comment: *“Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal”* – Is that error message not clear enough?

Comment: Copy the actual error message and paste it here in text, not as a picture. Also to get us to understanding the problem, put all the computational steps into variables so it is easier to understand which step is the problematic one.

Comment: Decimal can only take care of around 10^-29 to 10^29... 28-29 digit precision. Beyond that (say 10^30) it is not capable of handling

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to split your formula into steps on each step calculating one simple expression and assigning the result to a separate variable to be used on the next step. That will allow you to debug your calculations and see the ways to simplify final formula.

Answer (score 0):

decimal Range :
-79228162514264337593543950335M To 79228162514264337593543950335M
 double Range : 
1.7976931348623157E+308 To -1.7976931348623157E+308

Like This :

```
        // vyteznost_CO2_s_vysokym_tlakem = x1     it mustn't be 0.00
        // mars_g_acceleration =            x2     it mustn't be 0.00
        // martian_surface =                x3     it mustn't be 0.00

        decimal x1 = 1.11m,            
        decimal x2 = 1.11m;            
        double x3 = 1.11d;          

        double v1 = decimal.ToDouble(x1 * 1000000 * x2) / x3;
        double v2 = v1 * 0.813008D;
        double v3 = Convert.ToDouble(v2);
        double v4 = Math.Log10(v3);
        double v5 = Convert.ToDouble(v4 * 0.434294D);
        double v6 = Math.Log10(v5);

        decimal v7 = Convert.ToDecimal(-6164.64D / v6); //Result
```

`